# Create Multiple FORM + submit button to inset data into DB

Tags: php, html

I'm working on DATA entry web site.[data entry form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNwUI.png)

So i'm a newbie of html and PHP ad i need to know if there is a way to make each form for each record insert on array. Or can I create a static html page and submit record into DB(I already created).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help , but I did it my self.

I have four HTML element like that :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <span class="label warning">Prima Dispobinilita'</span>
    <p><span class="label classe">Classe D </span><input type="date" name="88731_D" required="" value=""><label class="container">Disponibilità Esautrita<input type="checkbox"id="!88731_D" name="!88731_D" value="true"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
    <p><span class="label classe">Classe P </span><input type="date" name="88731_P" required="" value=""><label class="container">Disponibilità Esautrita<input type="checkbox"id="!88731_P" name="!88731_P" value="true"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
```

When I press SUBMIT button , I get values into a variable , but for example if I have ten dates I need ten `$var;`

I know that itsn't a great solution , maybe i can use an Array in order to collect my values.
Any help is good for me.